# detect connection type for iphone on website?

Tags: iphone, networking, connection

is it possible with javascript, PHP (or anything!) to see if the iphone is using 3g or wifi from a website? We want to load low-res content if its 3G you see,

I found SCNetworkReachabilityFlags but that is just for apps...

Any pointers would be great!

Dan

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't expect this to be possible at all from the server side. From the client side, as you said, you could use the System Configuration Framework and the `SCReachabilityFlags`, but only client side.

As far as your server is concerned, it knows nothing about the type of connection any request is coming in on, apart from the immediate connection it has to the internet.

A request from an iPhone may pass through firewalls, routers, bridges, hubs, wireless, wired, almost any kind of network on it's way to you server.

The 3G part is only the connection between the phone and the data provider (AT&T, O2, etc), and after that, it's anybodies guess and will most certainly differ depending on the route between the data provider and your server.

The best advice I can give is to have a landing page, and let the user decide whether or not to load a high or low res version of the site. At least then it's off your hands if they run up a huge data bill...

Comment: cheers! do you think i can use SCReachabilityFlags as javascript on the webpage?

Comment: No, it's an Objective-C API and is only available to natively compiled applications.